# How to properly authenticate user in code behind and update LoginView accordingly

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created LoginView first time:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            Test
                         </LoggedInTemplate>
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                              Not loged in. 
                              <button type="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="LoginButton_Click" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Sign in</button>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

However, when I process button click `(LoginButton_Click)` that does login, Anonymous Template still appears.

How to do Login in code behind properly? I just found description of LoginView, but could not find any description of how to set login (property or something) so that LoginView knows that user is loged in.

I am using ASP.NET WebForms.

Comment: Include the portion of code you have in the code behind which actually authenticates the user.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: Code behind is not my code, but so far as I found - it does not use any built in login functionality. It simply queries db and writes data int session. So LoginView does not know anything... So I am looking for an example to implement.